# Image disapear when using align / justify-self

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a problem with my grid :

I am using a grid like this :

```
    .grid {

  display:grid;

  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr  1fr 1fr 1fr ;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr  1fr 1fr 1fr;


}
```

I have an image in the cell 3-3 :

```
.dice-pic {

  background-image: url(assets/dice_6.png);
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

I am trying to make this image in the center of the cell but when i add :

```
justify-self: center;
align-self: center;
```

my image disappear. Any idea how I could fix it ? thanks !

Comment: give the image `background: url(assets/dice_6.png) no-repeat center / contain` or cover

Comment: @c0dm1tu do you mean `background-repeat: no-repeat center;` ?

Comment: contain to fit the entire image inside the container, cover to cover the entire container with the image if image and container have different aspect ratios, you can also play with this [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.asp?filename=playcss_grid-area](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.asp?filename=playcss_grid-area)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use z-index, which should help you display your image on the top-level component.

Comment: While applying `z-index` could be correct, this answer doesn't include any code or information as to how `z-index` should be applied.